# Azure VM copy loop (VM naming convention_

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

`"name": "[concat(parameters('vm-name'),'-0', copyIndex(1))]",`

Hello, I am trying to loop around 20 vm's. Vm names should end with 01,02,03...10,11,12..20.

I am getting 010,011,012...obviously with hardcoded '-0' in the name. Is there any other easy way to get 10,11,12..20?

This may be a simple fix, help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to remove the "-0"  and use this  instead `"name": "[concat(parameters('vm-name'), copyIndex(1))]", ` then you will get VM names as 1,2,3,4...10,11,12... but not as 01,02....010,011...`

Comment: I understand that. But I want the names to be vm-test-01, vm-test-02...vm-test-10,vm-test-11& so on...Is there any way to do this? Thanks for the reply